# Get Text from Text Area and Set it BOLD on Label

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm basically just trying to get text from a text area and then display it on a Label in Bold format. Any suggestions? This is what the code looks like, but obviously it's not correct.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
  String sInput = TF_INPUT.getText();
  TA_OUTPUT.setText(Font.Bold,sInput);             
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't guess at what methods to call or how and what parameters to pass in -- that's what the Java API is for -- to **tell** exactly what's available. If you did this and looked up [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html), you'll see that it has a `setFont(...)` method that it gains from its JComponent parent and which you can and should use to set the font. Then look up Font to see what constructors are available (I often use the String, int, int constructor).  So it could be something like:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String sInput = tfInput.getText();
    taOutput.setText(sInput);      
    taOutput.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 24));
}
```

Also you can re-use a component's font by calling `getFont()` on it and then `deriveFont(...)` on the Font to make it bold or change its size.

Comment: Hi there mate. I'm just newly learning java, tried copy pasting your code and it didn't work :/

Comment: @MoeAbbas: that's your problem -- don't blindly copy and paste anything. Use your code, and get the ideas from us, but again use your code and write your methods. I've changed variable names for instance so that they comply with Java standards, and that's why blind copying and pasting won't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I sorted it out. I realise what you were trying to say. Also, after I made sense from your code, I realised  I was missing a library so I just imported it now. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, JLabel supports HTML. So everything you need to do is wrap your text in <b> tags.